# php to detect browser

Tags: php, cross-browser, browser-detection, php-5.2

Ive got an odd css fault that i cant seem to fix, its only occuring in safari, not chrome so webkit targeting wont help.. what i was trying to do is set a block of php to check if the browsers safari, if so echo a peice of css.

So far ive got this (bellow) - Which works, but its also outputting the echo statement in chrome, any idea were ive gone wrong ?

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
         $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }

    if(strlen(strstr($agent,"Safari")) > 0 ){
        $browser = 'safari';
    }
    if($browser=='safari'){
        echo '<style>p {font-weight: 300;}</style>';
    }

?>
```

Ive just been playing arround with `echo $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];` and this is what i get from safari

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17

and from chrome

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.22
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22

So it can tell its different browsers, but its obviously reading them both as Apple Web Kit, rather than safari or chrome. My php is a bit rusty how would i get it to target the safari user agent specificly ?

Comment: Why parse it yourself - there's a builtin function for that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: Because get_browser requires `browscap`, making it fundamentally useless.

Comment: Why don't you solve it on the client, where the problem exists?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a more general solution based on po228's answer.  I think it is easier to search directly for the version number of the browser, rather than the build number.

```
$ua = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];      // Get user-agent of browser

$safariorchrome = strpos($ua, 'Safari') ? true : false;     // Browser is either Safari or Chrome (since Chrome User-Agent includes the word 'Safari')
$chrome = strpos($ua, 'Chrome') ? true : false;             // Browser is Chrome

if($safariorchrome == true AND $chrome == false){ $safari = true; }     // Browser should be Safari, because there is no 'Chrome' in the User-Agent

// Check for version numbers 
$v1 = strpos($ua, 'Version/1.') ? true : false;
$v2 = strpos($ua, 'Version/2.') ? true : false;
$v3 = strpos($ua, 'Version/3.') ? true : false;
$v4 = strpos($ua, 'Version/4.') ? true : false;
$v5 = strpos($ua, 'Version/5.') ? true : false;
$v6 = strpos($ua, 'Version/6.') ? true : false;

// Test versions of Safari
if($safari AND $v1){ echo 'Safari Version 1'; }
else if($safari AND $v2){ echo 'Safari Version 2'; }
else if($safari AND $v3){ echo 'Safari Version 3'; }
else if($safari AND $v4){ echo 'Safari Version 4'; }
else if($safari AND $v5){ echo 'Safari Version 5'; }
else if($safari AND $v6){ echo 'Safari Version 6'; }
else if($safari){ echo 'Safari newer than Version 6'; }
else{ echo "Not Safari"; }
```

Comment: `$v1 = strpos($ua, 'Version/1.') ? true : false;` *whoah*

Answer (score 0):

I use this. this is not perfect, but it works

```
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$chrome = '/Chrome/';
$firefox = '/Firefox/';
$ie = '/MSIE/';
if (preg_match($chrome, $browser))
    echo "Chrome/Opera";
if (preg_match($firefox, $browser))
    echo "Firefox";
if (preg_match($ie, $browser))
    echo "Ie";
```

Comment: Why use `preg_match()` for something a simple string search will find?

Answer (score 0):

There are many open source projects for this request I suggest to add the class to your PHP project and run it when needed:
https://github.com/cbschuld/Browser.php

but if you just want to solve your issue acourding to your code I think this will do it:

```
$agent = '';
$browser = '';
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
     $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}

if(strlen(strstr($agent,'Safari')) > 0 ){
    $browser = 'safari';
   if(strstr($agent,'Chrome')){
     $browser= 'chrome';
   }
}

if($browser=='safari'){
    echo '<style>p {font-weight: 300;}</style>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved using the following code

```
$u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$issafari=false;
if (preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)){
    $issafari=(!preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.

```
function getBrowser($agent = null){
        $u_agent = ($agent!=null)? $agent : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
        $bname = 'Unknown';
        $platform = 'Unknown';
        $version= "";

        //First get the platform?
        if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'linux';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'mac';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'windows';
        }

        // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
        if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Internet Explorer'; 
            $ub = "MSIE"; 
        } 
        elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox'; 
            $ub = "Firefox"; 
        } 
        elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Google Chrome'; 
            $ub = "Chrome"; 
        } 
        elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Apple Safari'; 
            $ub = "Safari"; 
        } 
        elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Opera'; 
            $ub = "Opera"; 
        } 
        elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Netscape'; 
            $ub = "Netscape"; 
        } 

        // finally get the correct version number
        $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
        $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
        ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
        if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
            // we have no matching number just continue
        }

        // see how many we have
        $i = count($matches['browser']);
        if ($i != 1) {
            //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
            //see if version is before or after the name
            if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
                $version= $matches['version'][0];
            }
            else {
                $version= $matches['version'][1];
            }
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }

        // check if we have a number
        if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

        return array(
            'userAgent' => $u_agent,
            'name'      => $bname,
            'version'   => $version,
            'platform'  => $platform,
            'pattern'    => $pattern
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Safari (a `float: right;` refusing to sit alongside another column) ended up using JavaScript to detect the problem rather than the problem browser.

JavaScript code:

```js
function check() { //called by HTML's <body onLoad="check();">  
  topPos = document.getElementById("rightCol").offsetTop;
  //has rightCol been placed below leftCol ??   
  if (topPos > 200) {
    //if you want a message - something like this works  
    text = "Apologies to Safari (and other?) users: the important links   are at the bottom of the page." + topPos.toString();
    document.getElementById("warning").appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    //or, if you want to override your preferred styles something like this  
    document.getElementById("leftCol").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("rightCol").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("rightCol").style.borderTop = "thin dotted black";
  } else //removes the warning paragraph (if required)  
    document.getElementById("warning").normalise();
}
```

In Html:
 1. Add  `onLoad="check();"` to the body tag

2. Place `<p id="warning"></p>` for a special message
3. Give `id`'s to the elements you need to test or restyle

Answer (score 0):

Use This one definitly work, I already tested it---------

```
<?php
$msie = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'MSIE') ? true : false;
$firefox = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Firefox') ? true : false;
$safari = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Safari') ? true : false;
$chrome = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Chrome') ? true : false;
?>


<?php
//Firefox
if ($firefox) {
echo 'you are using Firefox!';
echo '<br />';
}

// Safari or Chrome. Both use the same engine - webkit
if ($safari || $chrome) {
echo 'you are using a webkit powered browser';
echo '<br />';
}

// IE
if ($msie) {
echo '<br>you are using Internet Explorer<br>';
echo '<br />';
}

// Not IE and for all other browsers
if (!$msie) {
echo '<br>you are not using Internet Explorer<br>';
echo '<br />';
}

// Add inline css
if ($firefox) {
echo '<style type="text/css">';
echo '.mydiv {position:relative; width:100px; height:50px;}';
echo '</style>';
}
?>
```

Original:- http://echopx.com/faq/browser-detection-ie-firefox-safari-chrome

Answer (score 0):

None of the strategies offered here seem to yield a truly valid result. To be almost hundred percent sure of what you are getting as the browser, use the [The Wolfcast BrowserDetection](https://github.com/Wolfcast/BrowserDetection) PHP class. With this class at your hands, it will be pretty easy to get both the browser and the platform, whether its on cellphone, desktop, or a MAC computer.

It detects browsers such as `Chrome, Edge, Firebird, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Internet Explorer Mobile, Opera, Opera Mini, Opera Mobile, Android, BlackBerry, BlackBerry Tablet OS, GNU IceCat, GNU IceWeasel, iCab, Konqueror, Lynx, Mozilla, MSN TV, Netscape, Nokia Browser, Phoenix, Safari, Samsung Internet, UC Browser.`

```
$browser = new Wolfcast\BrowserDetection();
if ($browser->getName() == Wolfcast\BrowserDetection::BROWSER_FIREFOX &&
    $browser->compareVersions($browser->getVersion(), '5.0') >= 0) {
    echo 'You are using FireFox version 5 or greater.';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try specific versions of Safari as well? I'm not on a Mac at the moment, so can't test this for you, but let me know if it helps:

```
$ua = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

$safari = strpos($ua, 'Safari') ? true : false; // All Safari
$safari_2 = strpos($ua, 'Safari/419') ? true : false; // Safari 2
$safari_3 = strpos($ua, 'Safari/525') ? true : false; // Safari 3
$safari_3_1 = strpos($ua, 'Safari/528') ? true : false; // Safari 3.1
$safari_4 = strpos($ua, 'Safari/531') ? true : false; // Safari 4

// Test Versions
if ($safari_2) { // Safari 2
    echo 'Safari Version 2';
}
elseif ($safari_3) { // Safari 3
    echo 'Safari Version 3';
}
elseif ($safari_4) { // Safari 4
    echo 'Safari Version 4';
}
```

Comment: i added this line - if ($safari) { // Safari
    echo 'Safari Version all';
} - just bellow the //Test Versions comment, and changed the $safari_2 statement to elseif and i got "safari version all", if i run you code exactly as above i get nothing.. i think this is becuase im running safari 6.02